# How to mock instantiating a new object with any not null parameter with JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, tdd, jmockit

I would like to mock the new instance of java.io.File with any not null parameter with JMockit. Here is the code

```
newInstance("java.io.File", (String) withNotNull(), (String) withNotNull());
```

But it keeps saying `Invalid null value passed as argument 0` and I don't know why because the first parameter is `withNotNull()`

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The above method call will match `File(String parent, String child)` constructor in `java.io.File` API.

From the error, we can understand that the argument `parent` passed to the constructor is `null` which it shouldn't be.

That's why it is throwing the error

Comment: But I passed withNotNull() as the first parameter, so it should be something not null.

Comment: The expectation is that it should be not `null`. But, the value passed during test is `null`. Can you please add how you get this error?